# Flutter run command is very slow on iPhone

Tags: flutter

Recently I noticed that the Flutter run command is very slow on iPhone.  I am using iPhone 14 Pro real device with iOS 16.2. My app is using Flutter with Firebase.  The build takes over 10 minutes to complete if I am lucky.  I have had times when I had to wait for 20 minutes or more. I have tried to use the release mode but did not help.

Does anyone know how to speed it up?
Thanks

Comment: Do you have firebase packages?

Comment: Yes, I am using firebase with flutter in my app.  I have updated the post.

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/4284 take a look at this, this might help you

Comment: It would be very difficult to ascertain this without know what you are trying to build, especially the dependencies. Also the device that you are building on

Comment: I have already mentioned the device is iPhone 14 Pro real device with iOS 16.2.

Comment: As Ahmad Raza said, I used the link provided.  I used tag => '10.3.0'.  The xcode build went from 500s to 172s.  It is better than before but still slow.